# Apex Interactive Report ORA-1843

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-apex-5

I'm trying to display at oracle apex IR query, a biggest date from 3 different tables, using greatest function to choice the biggest. For that, created two varchar2 type functions.

***One of them return the date converted to char, of a selected table like this:***

```
    create or replace FUNCTION RETURN_DATES (key in number, parameter in NUMBER)
    RETURN VARCHAR2 IS

    ...
BEGIN
        case parameter

                when 1  then 
                    select distinct MAX(mydate) into seal  from table1 v  WHERE v.num_contract = number_contract;
                   return NVL(TO_CHAR(TO_DATE (seal),'mm/dd/yyyy'),'01/01/1980')
                when 2 then 
                    select... from table2 x WHERE...
...
END;
```

***The second function calls that one using a greatest function between the parameter calls, which refers to case statement:***

```
    create or replace FUNCTION RETURN_BIGGEST_DATE(key in number) return VARCHAR2 IS

    ...
BEGIN
         select greatest (RETURN_DATES(key,1),RETURN_DATES(key,2),RETURN_DATES(key,3)) into greatest_date from dual;    
         return greatest_date;
...
END;
```

When i call it on sql commands it's works fine, but at an interactive report its fails, returning the ORA-1843, using the quite same query.

Could anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

Simply modifying the RETURN_DATES returning DATE

and the seal variable, of date type, without conversions, works fine at apex IR!
I noticed when a date column is relayed on ir query, there are an extra parameter on Column filter, named *Date Ranges*. It was the two way traffic to start simulations and change the returning type of the that function.

No more changes was required:

```
create or replace FUNCTION RETURN_DATES (key in number, parameter in NUMBER)
    RETURN DATE IS

...

     select distinct MAX(mydate) into seal  from table1 v  WHERE v.num_contract = number_contract;
                       return NVL(seal),'01/01/1980')
```